# Java Program to View the file Diff

Tags: file-diffs

**Result.jsp :**

```
    <%@page import="org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@page import="util.Utility"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="3">
            <tr>
                <th align="center"><b>Current BootConf</b></th>
                <th><b>New BootConf</b></th>
            </tr>
            <%
                ArrayList<String> currentHacks = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("currentHacks");
                ArrayList<String> newHacks = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("newHacks");
                int size = currentHacks.size() > newHacks.size() ? currentHacks.size() : newHacks.size();
                Iterator<String> current = currentHacks.iterator();
        /*      String cur[]=new String[currentHacks.size()];
                String newBootconf[]=new String[newHacks.size()]; */
                String cur[]=new String[size];
                String newBootconf[]=new String[size];
                int count=0;
                while (current.hasNext()) {
                    cur[count]=(String)current.next();
                    count++;        
                }
                count=0;
                Iterator<String> new_hacks = newHacks.iterator();
                while (new_hacks.hasNext()) {
                    newBootconf[count]=(String)new_hacks.next();
                    count++;        
                }
                for(int i=0;i<size;i++){ %>
            <tr>
                <%

                if(!Utility.replaceNull(cur[i]).equalsIgnoreCase(Utility.replaceNull(newBootconf[i]))){

                %>
                <td bgcolor="red"><%= Utility.replaceNull(cur[i])%></td>
                <td bgcolor="red"><%= Utility.replaceNull(newBootconf[i])%></td>
                <%}else{ %>
                <td><%= Utility.replaceNull(cur[i])%></td>
                <td><%= Utility.replaceNull(newBootconf[i])%></td>
                <%}%>
            </tr>
            <%}
            %>

        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**ServletDiff.java**

**DoGet Method:**

```
    ArrayList<String> currentHacks = readFile(currentFolderPath, hacks);
    ArrayList<String> newHacks = readFile(newFolderPath, hacks);
    request.setAttribute("currentHacks",currentHacks);
    request.setAttribute("newHacks",newHacks);
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher; 
    requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);

**Method to Read File**

   public ArrayList<String> readFile(String folderPath, String fileName) {
    File f =null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    String line = null;
    ArrayList<String> result= new ArrayList<String>();
    int count=0;
    try {
        f=new File(folderPath + "\\" + fileName);
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result.add(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(line));
            count++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}`
```

**Utility Class**

```
 public static String replaceNull(String input) {
    return input == null ? "" : input;
 }
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VOUoR.png

Comment: https://fulfillment.mp.microsoft.com/v2.0/rma/label/52b51605d28f4606b6ff8414f12bc444?MS-CorrelationId=12fc2d69-3ac0-4f80-a353-52289f44a934&MS-RequestId=00a6666b-399e-452a-9353-b64971503e36&MS-Contract-Version=2